# Protection For Web Service - Is Https Enough?

Tags: c#

I want to create a distributed application and I want to be using Web services so that I could consent with the other systems because there will be a version running on mobile and other computer and other smart hours.
But what worries me is being able to protect the application because it would be a lot of data and there will be great to adopt it.
Is HTTPS protocol enough to protect data during transmission and enough inability to eavesdrop on?

my English is poor i use google translate and not very good in that but is the better>
thx

Comment: It is not fully clear to me *what* you want to protect. You won't protect an application with HTTPS, but rather the communication. Why do you want to protect the communication? Do you have a login-mechanism, where you want to protect the data that is being sent? Do you want to protect the data/content of responses itself, as it may contain sensitive information? Do you need to protect the data stored in the client applications?

Comment: what i mean i have data access layer and business layer and DB in server (WEb Service) and i want other apps Work between other use this web service and like that what i need to protection this way HTTPS and what??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS should suffice if the whole question circles around the transmission of data between the server and the client. If the data is EXTREMELY sensitive, implement some kind of encryption for the data itself, but in most cases, yes SSL/TLS will do the trick. I would be more worried about getting a proper authentication solution in Place to protect access in the first place.

Comment: what i mean i have data access layer and business layer and DB in server (WEb Service) and i want other apps Work between other use this web service and like that what i need to protection this way HTTPS and what??

Comment: You need HTTPS for protection of the data going between the web service and the client application. But you also need some form of authentication handling set up so you know that only authorized users can access the data. Otherwise, if I were to set up a client that would communicate with your webservice it would return the data over HTTPS (which would make it hard for anyone else to see the data in transit, but the client would get it. If you have both authentication and HTTPS, you limit WHO can access the data itself aswell as making it hard for anyone to eavesdrop.